# JavaScript code is displayed after login into ASP.MVC4 web

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Problem is that sometimes after login to asp.mvc4 web javascript code is displayed on the screen as text. This occurs randomly and only on deployed version.

For some reason code from this js file is displayed:

```
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/notifications").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/notifications_count.js"));
```

This is method that handles login:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(User user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && user.ResetPassword)
        {
            if (AisLogin.AisVerification(user, user.Password) != null)
            {
                UserMethods.ResetPassword(user);
            }
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid && user.Name != null && user.Password != null)
        {
            string pass = user.Password;
            user.Password = CRSecurity.HashPassword(user.Password);

            var ActUser = UserMethods.IsValid(user.Name, user.Password);
            if (ActUser != null)
            {
                Session["User"] = ActUser;
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(ActUser.Name, user.RememberMe);
                CreateProjectCookie("projectPropId");
                CreateProjectCookie("projectRepositoryId");
            }
            else
            {
                //Skus sa pozriet do ais, ci taky neexistuje, ak ano, vrat ho
                ActUser = AisLogin.TryRegister(user, pass);
                if (ActUser != null)
                {
                    Session["User"] = ActUser;
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(ActUser.Name, user.RememberMe);
                    CreateProjectCookie("projectPropId");
                    CreateProjectCookie("projectRepositoryId");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login data is incorrect! If you forgot your password, write your current AIS credentials and check Reset Password");
                    return View(user);
                }
            }

            if (ActUser != null)
            {
                //Nacitanie projektov z databazy
                ProjectMethods.ReadProjectsFromASTRCS();


                if (Session["ReturnUrl"] != null
                    && !((string)Session["ReturnUrl"]).Equals(@"/")
                    && !((string)Session["ReturnUrl"]).Contains("jquery"))
                {
                    Logger.Info("Return URL:" + (string)Session["ReturnUrl"]);
                    return RedirectToLocal((string)Session["ReturnUrl"]);
                }

                if(!ActUser.UserRoles.Any(x => x.RoleId == (int)UserRolesEnum.Administrator))
                    return RedirectToAction("UsersProjectsIndex", "ProjectsManager");
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }

        ModelState.AddModelError("", "You must fill in all of the fields !");
        return View(user);
    }
```

Screen that is displayed after login:

[image: Screen after login]

Thank you for your advices.

Comment: This means that the URL that is currently selected is serving up that JavaScript file. It'd be like navigating to that JS file directly.

Comment: Of course but why is it happening. Why it is redirected to that URL. It shoulnd be ..

Comment: What's the controller called?  What routes do you have?